# How to resolve SQL syntax error; check the manual that corresponds MariaDB server for right version?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax-error, mariadb, mariasql

I am developing a CRUD in that whenever i am trying to upgrade items it show me "You have an error in your Sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds MariaDB server for right for right syntax to use near 'Name = as', Last Name = 's' WHERE ID = '32' at Line 120 "

I know its a very minute error which is not coming in my notice. Plz help me out.

And thanks in Advance

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static string conString = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=testc1;";
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //DataGridView Properties
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Id";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "First Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Last Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Address";

        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        //selection mode
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;

    }

    // string connectionString = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=test;";
    //"SELECT * FROM `user1"

    private void Add(string firstname, string lastname, string team)
    {
        //string conString = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=test;";
        string sql = "INSERT INTO user1(`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `address`) VALUES (NULL, '" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "')";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

        //Open connection and excute insert
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>=0)
            {
                ClearText();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Inserted");
            }

            con.Close();

            Retrieve();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    //add to dgview
    private void populate(String id, String first_name, String last_name, String address)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(id, first_name, last_name, address);
    }


    //for retrieving from db
    private void Retrieve()
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        //SQL Statement 
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM `user1`";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

        //Open con, retrieve, fill DGview
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            adapter.Fill(dt);

            //loop through dt
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                populate(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString());

            }
            con.Close();

            //clear dt

            dt.Rows.Clear();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    //update db
    private void Update(int id, string first_name, string last_name, string add)
    {
        //sql stmt
        string sql = "UPDATE user1 first_name = @firstname, last_name = @lastname, add = @address WHERE id = @id";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", first_name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", last_name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", add);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

        //Open con, update, retrieve dgview 
        try
        {

            con.Open();
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand();
            adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql;

            if (adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()>= 0)
            {
                ClearText();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully");
            }

            con.Close();

            Retrieve();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    //Deleting Db
    private void Delete(int id)
    {
        //sql stmt
        string sql = "DELETE FROM user1 WHERE ID=" + id + "";
        cmd =  new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

        //open con, excute delete, close con
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.DeleteCommand = con.CreateCommand();
            adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = sql;

            //promt for confirmation 
            if (MessageBox.Show("Sure??", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)== DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>=0)
                {
                    ClearText();
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
                }
            }


            con.Close();

            Retrieve();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    //cleat textbox

    private void ClearText()
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    }

    private void Addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
    }

    private void Retrievebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Retrieve();
    }

    private void Updatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String selected = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(selected);

        Update(id, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
    }

    private void Deletebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String selected = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(selected);

        Delete(id);
    }

    private void Clearbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: 99% of that code is irrelevant. Post only the query that is failing.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `sql` that fails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 2):

The immediate cause of your problem is a missing single quote around the `ID`.  The immediate fix is to add the closing single quote, but the better fix is to use prepared statements properly:

```
string sql = "UPDATE user1 `First Name` = @firstname, `Last Name` = @lastname, Address = @address WHERE ID = @id";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", first_name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", last_name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", add);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

Note that I also escaped the `First Name` and `Last Name` columns in backticks, because they have whitespace in their names.  You should generally avoid whitespace in your table and column names.

There may be other problems with your code, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: @SurajSewatkar Few people on this site will have the patience to debug your entire code.  I have pointed out and corrected what appears to be the biggest problem.  You may still have other issues in your code.

Comment: i made the desired change in my code n now its giving fatal error. plz guide me

Comment: Just repeating "now its giving fatal error" doesn't actually provide any more information. Please reduce the problem to a [mcve], and post a *new* question (as it's unlikely to be the same cause as the one described by this question).